# use flags for country list call from SQL in php

Tags: php, html, sql

i have a form for choose country that list call from sql
now how can put flags for all

```
<div class="col-xs-12 marpad">
  <div class="labelsrch">Going from</div>
  <div class="inputwrp mapmrkr">
    <select class="custmselct padspl" name="nationality" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected">Tell us where are you from</option>
      <?php 
                   foreach($country as $each_countries){
                    ?>
        <option value="<?=$each_countries->iso_code?>">
          <?=$each_countries->country_name?>
        </option>
        <?php
                   }
                   ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Where are you getting your list of countries? And your flag assets?  Do you store information in a database?

Comment: contries list in SQL and have ISO CODE another page i use CSS for flags

Answer (score 0):

you can use flags and select box from Semantic-UI: http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#form (see Country select box)

and change < i > class to the abbreviation country name for example "ir": < i class="ir flag">< /i>

you must get this name from Database

```
   <div class="field">
      <label>Country</label>
      <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden" name="country">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
        <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="af"><i class="af flag"></i>Afghanistan</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ax"><i class="ax flag"></i>Aland Islands</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="al"><i class="al flag"></i>Albania</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="dz"><i class="dz flag"></i>Algeria</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="as"><i class="as flag"></i>American Samoa</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ad"><i class="ad flag"></i>Andorra</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ao"><i class="ao flag"></i>Angola</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ai"><i class="ai flag"></i>Anguilla</div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can't use this method bcuz my list call from SQL :)

Comment: give me an output example for "$each_countries->iso_code" in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use some existing codes for this as this one:
[Flags](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css)

I would insert into database image name or link with country name and id. And with ajax on country name typing show the flag.